keyrings.google-artifactregistry.auth for python AR repo without a service account JSON key
I don't use non-expiring service account JSON keys; I use ambient creds and OIDC everywhere, so I can't generate and use json keys for AR.
I want to do pip installs in my Dockerfiles to install my private AR packages.
Doing something like this works:
# Passing in a non expiring key
docker build -f "Dockerfile" \
    --secret id=gcp_creds,src="gsa_key.json" .

##### IN DOCKERFILE
# I don't want to generate json keys like this
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/run/secrets/gcp_creds

RUN pip install keyring keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth 
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=gcp_creds \
    --mount=type=cache,target=target=/root/.cache \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

Does keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth support tokens somehow?
This did not work for example:
# GSA is active through ambient creds or impersonation
gcloud auth print-access-token > /tmp/token.json
# also tried: gcloud config config-helper --format="json(credential)" > /tmp/token.json

docker build -f "Dockerfile" \
    --secret id=gcp_creds,src="/tmp/token.json" .

I'd like to avoid resorting to doing something like building outside of the container and copying the built artifacts in the image. I want to do the build inside the Dockerfile.
EDIT
So I got this working with GCP provided GH actions tooling so I know it's possible to generate temp tokens in a format the keyring will accept. I still want to know how to do this with the gcloud cli for other scenarios.
Using the Dockerfile above and these GH actions steps I can auth via OIDC and generate a creds file the pip keyring provider accepts:
- id: 'auth'
  name: 'auth to gcp'
  uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
  with:
    token_format: 'access_token'
    workload_identity_provider: 'projects/xxxxx/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/github/providers/github'
    service_account: xxxxxxxx

- name: Set up Docker Buildx
  uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

- uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
  with:
    push: false
    context: '.'
    file: 'Dockerfile'
    tags: myimage:mytag
    load: true
    cache-from: type=gha,scope=localbuild
    cache-to: type=gha,mode=max,scope=localbuild
    secret-files: |
      gcp_creds=${{steps.auth.outputs.credentials_file_path}}


Normally, you don't need to set a credentials file in the Dockerfile. Instead, you can use authentication via Application Default Credentials (ADC).
The keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth package works seamlessly with ADC.
For example, if you want to test your Dockerfile locally, you can mount the short-lived credentials generated by ADC as a volume after authentication.
First, authenticate your local machine with Google Cloud using:
gcloud auth application-default login

This command will generate short-lived credentials and save them to a known path in your gcloud configuration, such as:
Credentials saved to file: [/Users/current_user/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json]

Mounting Credentials in Docker
When running your Docker container, you can mount this credentials file as a volume into the container using the following command:
docker run -it \
   -v $HOME/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud \
   your_image

Authentication in CI/CD Pipelines
In the context of a CI/CD pipeline, such as with GitHub Actions, if you're using Workload Identity Federation or other authentication methods, there’s no need to pass credentials into the Dockerfile.
The container will automatically authenticate within the current execution context.

Your not understanding my question. I need AR auth at DOCKER BUILD time not run time (internal pypi repos). Also, Im talking about SERVICE ACCOUNT creds not user creds. Also, those default app creds are not temporary, they are much like service account json keys and by default don't expire. Per my GH actions solution the step generates temp creds in a format the keyring expects. I want to know how to do that myself.

Sorry for the misunderstanding.
Normally, from GitHub Actions (GHA), if you are authenticated to GCP, your container will be directly authenticated in GCP and can install the packages from Artifact Registry using Keyring.
Have you tried this approach?

There are different methods to authenticate to artifact registry. Since you prefer using temporary credentials, you can try using a short-lived OAuth access token for password authentication. However,  keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth relies on ADC or json credentials so the access token should follow a specific json file format.
As for AR authentication during docker build time, it is best practice to generate the access token using gcloud print-access–token before performing docker build.
I came across this StackOverflow post about injecting credentials to docker build. You can follow the suggestions made in the thread and see if those would help.
